# How to do a git diff on moved/renamed file?

Tags: git, diff, file-rename, mv

I moved a file using `git mv`. Now I would like to do a diff on the new file to compare it with the old file (with the old, now non-existent name).

How do I do this?

Comment: Soon (git 2.9, June 2016), a simple `git diff -- yourRenamedFile` will be enough. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36435527/6309)

Comment: @VonC don't you still need to include both the old and new filenames?

Comment: @TTT Not when doing a diff a the tree or commit level (instead of the file itself)

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You need to use -M to let git autodetect the moved file when diffing. Using just `git diff` as knittl mentioned does not work for me.

So simply: `git diff -M` should do it.

The documentation for this switch is:

```
-M[<n>], --find-renames[=<n>]
       Detect renames. If n is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity index 
       (i.e. amount of addition/deletions compared to the file’s size). For example, 
       -M90% means git should consider a delete/add pair to be a rename if more than
       90% of the file hasn’t changed.
```

Comment: Lifesaver!  My git diffs are so much better now.  1) Is it safe to always use this option?  2) Can I add this option as default behaviour to my `~/.gitconfig`?

Comment: Note that rename detection works only when both old and new files appear in the collection of files processed by `git diff`. Running `git diff -M` on a single (renamed) file doesn't report a rename.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, but `git log --follow -- file_after_move.txt` works well. It shows the whole history, including before the move. Any ideas? I am running `git version 2.11.0.windows.1`.

Comment: The `-C` option for detecting copies is useful and similar. I used it with `-M` for looking at a diff where I had refactored one file into two (with neither name matching the original).

Comment: But... How to do difftool? e.g. vim?

Answer (score 110):

In addition to what [knittl wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730460/git-diff-on-moved-file/5730597#5730597), you can always use:

```
git diff HEAD:./oldfilename newfilename
```

where `HEAD:./oldfilename` means oldfilename in the last commit (in HEAD), relative to current directory.

If you don't have new enough git, you would have to use instead:

```
git diff HEAD:path/to/oldfilename newfilename
```

Comment: Thanks for this. You can also specify a specific commit instead of head, i.e. `git diff 39fa7c77e85c51d43ea0cf30d33aec8721812e9e:./oldfilename newfilename`

Comment: In case it's unclear, you can also specify branch names or any other reference, such as: `git diff branch:old/filen.name newfilename`

Comment: The first form works for me, if you `cd` to the directory and do not add `--` before the `commit:path` pair. Git appears to be very picky with syntax here.

Comment: @dhardy The `<commit-ish>:<pathname>` syntax is an object identifier, something Git-ish; after `--` Git expects filenames only.

Comment: This syntax worked for me where -M just showed the entire file as having been changed - `git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)`.   It worked with or without the leading `./`. - Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

With git 2.9 (June 2016), you won't have to add `-M` anymore. [`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9276a69caeb116cf517a5feb70cd96efab23601) uses `-M` by default.

See [commit 5404c11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5404c116aa921d7e2f9408e103c80b7801735d08), [commit 9501d19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9501d191adca307d6fbe3f2ab111fa20414dd893), [commit a9276a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9276a69caeb116cf517a5feb70cd96efab23601), [commit f07fc9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f07fc9e753746cc4d7e57212f558106782e7bfa4), [commit 62df1e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62df1e68e0086d9d8dc65a76d99f72c265dcf852) (25 Feb 2016) by [Matthieu Moy (`moy`)](https://github.com/moy).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5d2a30d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d2a30d7d8777319c745804f040fa405d02169ce), 03 Apr 2016)</sup>

> ### `diff`: activate `diff.renames` by default
>
> Rename detection is a very convenient feature, and new users shouldn't
>   have to dig in the documentation to benefit from it.
>
> Potential objections to activating rename detection are that it
>   sometimes fail, and it is sometimes slow. But rename detection is
>   already activated by default in several cases like "`git status`" and "`git merge`", so activating `diff.renames` does not fundamentally change the
>   situation. When the rename detection fails, it now fails consistently
>   between "`git diff`" and "`git status`".
>
> This setting does not affect plumbing commands, hence well-written
>   scripts will not be affected.

[The new tests for this feature are here](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9276a69caeb116cf517a5feb70cd96efab23601).

Answer (score 4):

For whatever reason using `HEAD:./oldfilename` (or absolute path) didn’t work for me, but `HEAD:oldfilename` did (thanks cmn):

```
git diff HEAD:oldfilename newfilename
git diff 2a80f45:oldfilename f65f3b3:newfilename
```

HTH

Comment: Perhaps your git is too old to understand `HEAD:./oldfilename`?

Comment: This is the most general answer available here. `-M` does not seem to work if the file has been edited too much.

Answer (score 2):

`git diff -M` activates rename detection as others have said (and as @VonC pointed out, it is activated by default from git 2.9). But if you have a large changeset, inexact rename detection may still get turned off again.  Git will display a warning like the following, which is easy to miss amidst the diff you are viewing:

```
warning: inexact rename detection was skipped due to too many files.
warning: you may want to set your diff.renameLimit variable to at least 450 and retry the command.
```

In that case, set the configuration option as suggested by git, for example

```
git config diff.renamelimit 450
```

and re-run your diff command.

Answer (score -6):

simply run `git diff` without any arguments, or `git diff -- newfilename`. git is smart enough to compare the right files/contents (i.e. original content before rename with altered content after rename)

Comment: git is absolutely not smart enough in most cases. Simply `git mv`ing a single file and then comparing the staged state to another otherwise-identical branch will produce the "everything was deleted and recreated again" diff unless `-M` is used.