# git: view log and changes of moved file

Tags: git, git-log, file-move

I have file in git and want to check it's history: commits when it was changed and what exactly was changed between this commits.

But:

1. I know that I have renamed the file in the past git history
2. May be
   even have moved between directories.

What is the easiest way to check what I want to check?

P.S. I know about this question: [git diff on moved file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730460/git-diff-on-moved-file), but there is not answer what to do if you have a bad memory and don't remember all previous file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the history of a file even across file moves or renames it's best to use:

```
git log --follow FILENAME
```

Comment: and I found command like "git diff HEAD^^^^ HEAD --follow FILENAME". Very nice. Thanks.