# git diff --staged on moved file?

Tags: git, git-diff, mv

This question is the same as the following question:
[How to do a git diff on moved/renamed file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730460/git-diff-on-moved-file)
but with the important distinction that I want to see the changes between the version of the file in the previous commit, and the version that is currently staged.

git diff --staged shows the whole file being deleted in one side:

```
--- a/old_path/main.cpp
+++ /dev/null
@@ -0,0 +1,42 @@
- line 1
- line 2
- line 3
- etc.
```

and the whole file being added on another:

```
--- /dev/null
+++ b/new_path/main.cpp
@@ -0,0 +1,42 @@
+ line 1
+ line 2
+ line 2.5
+ line 3
+ etc.
```

without any convenient way of comparing the actual differences between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is a bit different if you're looking at past commits, but the use of `git diff --staged` suggests you're looking for the difference between `old_path/main.cpp` in `HEAD` and your currently staged `new_path/main.cpp`, which was derived from the old file. In this case, this command should work, assuming that there have been no new changes to `new_path/main.cpp` since it was staged:

```
git diff HEAD:old_path/main.cpp new_path/main.cpp
```

Not sure how to specify exactly the version that is in the index for the second path in the case where `new_path/main.cpp` also contains additional changes that have not been staged yet...

Edit: after a little reading in `gitrevisions(7)` it would appear that this should handle the latter case:

```
git diff HEAD:old_path/main.cpp :new_path/main.cpp
```

Note the `:` with no revision prefix, which should specify the version that is in the index.

Comment: +1, thanks. I wanted the second one, which works for my purposes (new_path/main.cpp contains both staged and unstaged changes). The first one gives what git diff --staged already gave.

Comment: man gitrevisions mentions "stage numbers (0 to 3)" but does not seem to define what there numbers correspond to... man git-stage/git-add appear to also be mute on the subject. Any idea?

Comment: Hmmm... maybe you need a newer version of the `git` man-pages... Mine (v1.7.12.3) says this under the `:<n>:<path>` heading of `gitrevisions(7)`: "A missing stage number ... names a stage 0 entry. During a merge, stage 1 is the common ancestor, stage 2 is the target branch's version ..., and stage 3 is the version from the branch which is being merged."

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know the answer to the question above, I usually use a roundabout way: whenever convenient, and especially whenever I remember, I make a file move change in a separate commit. Thus, once the move is committed, I can continue working on the file and can do a normal git diff --staged in the 'normal' way, preparing for the next commit. This is the easiest way that I know... the problem is, sometimes I forget to do it this way...