# List of moved files from patch

Tags: linux, git, patch

I have a patch file generated from git. Is there any possibility to get list of moved (or renamed) files from it? 
I need this because I want to apply this patch to other version control system and if I do the simple remove/create I will lost all file history.

Answer (score 0):

use -M:

> -M[], --find-renames[=]
>          Detect renames. If n is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity index (i.e. amount of addition/deletions compared to the
>   file’s size). For example, -M90% means Git should consider a
>          delete/add pair to be a rename if more than 90% of the file hasn’t changed. Without a % sign, the number is to be read as a
>   fraction, with a decimal point before it. I.e., -M5 becomes 0.5, and
>          is thus the same as -M50%. Similarly, -M05 is the same as -M5%. To limit detection to exact renames, use -M100%.

See: [How to do a git diff on moved/renamed file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730460/how-to-do-a-git-diff-on-moved-renamed-file)