# How to show a file from a specific commit that has been renamed between that commit and HEAD?

Tags: git

I know that to show a file at a certain commit, I use `git show <commit>:<file path>`. But this doesn't work if the file was renamed between the commit and HEAD, so is there a way to easily do this on the file without needing to manually figure out what the original filename was at that commit?

Answer (score 1):

You could start with:

```
git log --oneline --name-only -M -C -- afile
```

That would detect any rename, and allow you to check if:

- your `<commit>` is part of that list
- what is the actual name associated with that commit

Then you can use the right filename for `git show <commit>:<file path>`.

Note, in git 2.9 (June 2016):

- [`diff` activates rename detection by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36435527/6309),
- [`log --follow` improves rename  detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36615639/6309)

So make sure to use git 2.9 as well.

Comment: Did you mean `git log` here?

Comment: @torek Actually, I tested it with `git show` (since it uses the same options as `git log`), but yes, `git log` is more logical.